# K-Nearest Neighbor Alogrithm, without using knnsearch() in MATLAB, Absolute Distance

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, knn

I've been tasked with writing a K-Nearest Neighbor algorithm without using the built in MATLAB command, knnsearch().

I'm following the code provided here: 
    http://www.cs.tut.fi/sgn/arg/SGN-2806/exer1/knn.m

To work out the distances, I'm using absolute differences.

My training data will look like this:

```
training data = [0 1 3 4 5 0 3 4 9 1 35 13 29 1 3]
```

Sample data to calculate knn, this:

```
inputdata = [1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1 3]
```

This is what I am using to calculate absolute differences:

```
distancesbetweendata = abs(bsxfun(@minus, inputdata(1:N)), trainingdata(N-1));
```

This returns 0/empty

Is this correct?

In the code  I'm following, the data is prepared such as:

```
N = size(sampleData,1);  % N is length of data
M = size(sampleData,2);  % M is index for class
```

However it uses data with multiple rows, whereas I am just using one.

How should I prepare my data in this instance?

Edit:

How to calculate output:

```
[sorted, idx] = sort(distance);

classes = sampleData(idx(1:min(N, k)));

resultClass = mode(classes); %OUTPUT
```

Comment: Please add your output as well..

Comment: No. Add the output of `distancesbetweendata`. You are asking if that is correct. You also have to make it clear what the trainingdata and the input data is. Add something like `inputdata = ...` etc to make it clear.

Comment: distancesbetweendata returns 0, initial data and training data is above, but I'll label it better

Comment: @user3089 - Your question has already been answered.  The duplicate post that I referred you to shows a detailed implementation of KNN without the use of `knnsearch`.

Comment: That is for finding the euclidian distance, I've altered the title

Comment: @user3089 - I recently edited my post to accommodate for the Manhattan / absolute distance.  You should check out the post again, and I'm still closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @user3089 - Even though I'm leaving as a duplicate, what's wrong with your implementation is that you are forgetting to sum all of the absolute distances together.

Comment: I tried implementing it, but the manhattan distances cause errors, 'Matrix dimensions must agree.'  I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original post

Comment: @rayryeng dists = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, x, sample)), 2); -- this gives me: Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other.             

dists = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, x, sample)), 2); this gives me -- Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other.

Comment: You need to read how the inputs are shaped.  `x` is a `M x N` array where `M` is the number of samples and `N` is the dimensionality of the sample.  `sample` is a `1 x N` input.  Make sure your data conforms to this shaping before running the code.  This is also the same way that `knnsearch` accepts inputs.  This is where I will stop replying as you really need to read the post carefully.